# Оптимизация приложения Android(SQlite)

Tags: android, sqlite, оптимизация

Я занимаюсь доработкой\оптимизацией уже работающего приложения для сбора статистики, реализовано на API 10 БД на Sqlite. 
  Приложение состоит в основном из списка статистических данных, в котором через диалог можно править данные...
  Сейчас объем списка до 2000 строк, но постоянно растет. После последнего обновления и добавления определенных функциональностей, работать со списком стало не комфортно, появилась ощутимая задержка от нажатия до исполнения.
  Еще все усложнено тем, что само приложение писал не я, да и человек этот не слишком доступен.

Изучил [статью](http://habrahabr.ru/company/sebbia/blog/243537/)
но метод устранения только понимаю как присвоить объекту     `null`

Изучил [такой метод](http://habrahabr.ru/post/154931/), но не совсем его понимаю, да и пообщавшись с человеком писавшим код, понял что его реализация почти не отличается от представленной.

Поработав над проблемой у меня есть 3 версии:
1) Нужно оптимизировать работу с базой, сделать запросы более сложные что бы получать необходимые данные одним запросам, а не несколькими.
2) Поиск и устранение "грязного кода", из-за которого могут потребляться лишние ресурсы
3) Возможно есть в коде метод, который самостоятельно портит всю производительность, найти его проблематично т.к. код чужой и не слишком дружелюбный

Хочу спросить следующее:

1. Где и как искать в приложении на Android самые ресурсоемкие места?
2. С помощью чего анализировать код на "чистоту".
3. Как исправлять
           найденные бреши в производительности и т.п.
4. С чего начать вообще.

Вот я нашел "утечку" (см. [статью](http://habrahabr.ru/company/sebbia/blog/243537/)), если в большинстве случаев это некая переменная которую нужно обнулить в методе `onPause()`, то здесь для меня не понятно как "обнулить" `mContext`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Начните с прочтения: Роберт Мартин  - "Чистый код. Создание, анализ и рефакторинг" и Джошуа Блох - "Эффективное программирование на Java"

Comment: Почитайте вот эти статьи, думаю поможет. http://habrahabr.ru/post/123707/   http://www.mobilab.ru/j2medev/javaperformanceoptimization.html http://apps4all.ru/post/08-28-14-poleznye-priemy-po-optimizatsii-android-prilozhenij-na-h86 http://habrahabr.ru/company/intel/blog/202088/